# Rails : user_addresses vs @shipping_address of a User in form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for, nested-form-for

I've got a User who's got multiple UserAddress

When I use :

```
<%= f.fields_for :user_addresses do |f| %>
```

My hash is nice :

```
"user_addresses_attributes"=>
    {"0"=>{"default"=>"0", "name"=>"chez mamie", "address1"=>"", "address2"=>"", "address3"=>"", "postal_code"=>"", "city"=>"", "_destroy"=>"0", "id"=>"105672"},
     "1"=>{"default"=>"0", "name"=>"billing", "address1"=>"32, rue du Loup", "address2"=>"", "address3"=>"", "postal_code"=>"33000", "city"=>"Bordeaux", "_destroy"=>"0", "id"=>"105673"},
     "2"=>{"default"=>"1", "name"=>"shipping", "address1"=>"1,rue doudou", "address2"=>"", "address3"=>"", "postal_code"=>"33000", "city"=>"Bordeaux", "_destroy"=>"0", "id"=>"105671"}},
```

But I need to do multiple nested forms with scopes.
Here I define :

```
@shipping = @user.user_addresses.find_by(name:"shipping")
```

Then call :

```
<%= f.fields_for @shipping do |f| %>
```

My User hash is bad, cause it's not containing user_addresses_attributes :

```
"user_address"=>{"default"=>"0", "name"=>"billing", "address1"=>"32, rue du Loup", "address2"=>"", "address3"=>"", "postal_code"=>"33000", "city"=>"Bordeaux", "_destroy"=>"0"}},
```

Any hint ?

Answer (score 0):

Tyr passing the name of the relation as a symbol as the first argument to `fields_for`

Comment: You mean 
    <%= f.fields_for @shipping, as: :user_addresses do |f| %> ?
Yes did it but it's not changing anything

Comment: I think I've tried all combinaisons now. Don't you think the solution could be around this : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#using-form-helpers ?

Comment: Right topic is 7.3 Using Form Helpers